Is there a way to make a GA4 report that shows page views for all pages over time at a specified frequency (daily, weekly, monthly, etc.)?
I want to create a report of the google analytics data (GA4) for my site that shows the page views for all pages over a specified length of time and broken down into smaller time chunks instead of all added together. Is there a way to do that?
For example, instead of saying that I have had 25680 views to my homepage over the last year, would there be a way to get the report to break those views down by month so I could see which months pages were more popular than others?
P.S. Also, how would I go about doing the same thing in the old google analytics as well? My site data is split with the majority of it being stored on the older non-ga4 tag.

From what I can tell there isn't a way to generate that report in google analytics. To accomplish this I had to filter the page view list to the frequency I wanted (a month for me), and go month by month downloading each of those reports and merge them into a larger google sheet by hand
